# Control python code through HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Hi i am making a Robot control system, i want to control it through a website i have made. However, i cant find a way to link this up to python code to control the Raspberry pi GPIO.

The active version of my website is at www.awesomecoding.co.uk and here is the source code of the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #commands{
            text-align: center;
            color: FF8300;
            font-size: 100px;
        }
        .controllbox{
            width: 610px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #arrowUp{
            text-align: center;
            position: static;
        }
        #arrowRight{
            text-align: right;
            position: static;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        #arrowDown{
            text-align: center;
            position: static;
        }
        #arrowLeft{
            text-align: left;
            position: static;
            margin-top: -200px;

        }
        #stop{
            width: 120px; 
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: -65%;
            margin-left: 34%;
            text-align: center;
            position: static;


        }
    </style>
</head>
 <body>

    <h1 id="commands">Controll Me!!</h1>
    <div class="controllBox">
        <div id="arrowUp"><img src="arrowUp.jpg" class="controll" id="button1"></div>
        <div id="arrowRight"><img src="arrowRight.jpg" class="controll" id="button2"></div>
        <div id="arrowLeft"><img src="arrowLeft.jpg" class="controll" id="button3"></div>
        <div id="arrowDown"><img src="arrowDown.jpg" class="controll" id="button4"></div>
        <div id="stop"><img src="stop.jpg" class="controll" id="button5"></div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function(){
           document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Foward' 
        }
        document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Right'
        }
        document.getElementById('button3').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Left'
        }
        document.getElementById('button4').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Backwards'
        }
        document.getElementById('button5').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('commands').innerHTML = 'Stop'
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

I am looking to see if anyone knows of an easy yet lag free way to do this. 
I thank you for and advice you can add towards this project i am doing.

Answer (score -1):

the best and easy way is to use python flask framework at the back-end
[Flask Doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/),
[Flask Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/)

Comment: Thanks for that, that confirms my suspicions, that a great help and i will look into it.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Pyscript is a new development project that will allow you to implement Python code directly into your HTML document.

First add the following into your `<head>` section like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then just input these tags inside of your `<head>` or `<body>` tags.
`<py-script>`
*Your code here*
`</py-script>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: WASM runs in a sandbox in the browser  it does not have access to GPIO on any computer, let alone on a *different* computer (i.e. the server)